# Apache mpm-worker + mod_fcgid + php5_cgi partially and sporadically down

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, mpm-worker

Recently, I have changed from Apache mpm-prefork (PHP module) to mpm-worker (PHP-FPM) due to memory issues. I am running a quite-large PHP application that requires ~20-30M per prefork process.

Overall, the server runs stable and fast. However, from time to time, the page is unavailable to **some** users for a few minutes.

Working hypothesis 1 (=rough idea) is that one of the processes (usually 2, sometime up to 5 or 6) hangs and each client assigned to this process (e.g. 50% of the clients) receives an error message.

Working hypothesis 2 is that MaxRequestsPerProcess is responsible. After 500 calls, the process tries to shut down, mod_fcgid does not gracefully kill and while the process is waiting for the kill, further clients are assigned to (and rejected by) the process. But I cannot really imaging that Apache would be so stupid.

My problem is: There is nothing in the error logs except some

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: process ???? graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

I am running out of ideas where to trace the problem. It appears sporadically and I have not yet managed to provoke it. Server performance (CPU/RAM) shall not be an issue, as the overall load has been in the lower range the recent weeks.

Thanks for any hints. Any comments on my hypotheses (that did not help my to find a solution, yet - I tried to disable the MaxRequestsPerProcess but do not yet know if it helped)? I would greatly appreciate some ideas how to trace this problem.

**Apache configuration**

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
           ...

            # PHP FCGI
            <FilesMatch \.php$>
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
            </FilesMatch>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FcgidWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-starter .php
            # Allow request up to 33 MB
            FcgidMaxRequestLen 34603008
            FcgidIOTimeout 300
            FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
            # Set 1200 (>1000) for PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS to avoid problems
            FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
    </IfModule>
```

**Apache module configuration**

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
  FcgidConnectTimeout 20
  FcgidBusyTimeout 7200

  DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
  IdleTimeout 600
  IdleScanInterval 60
  MaxProcessCount 20

  MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
  PHP_Fix_Pathinfo_Enable 1
</IfModule>
```

Note: The timeout was set to 2 hours because rarely, the application may require some time to run (e.g. the nightly cronjob that does a database optimization).

**Starter script**

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1200
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS

export PHPRC="/etc/php5/cgi"
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi

#PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=10
#export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
```

**Package versions**

- System: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
- apache2-mpm-worker: 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4
- libapache2-mod-fcgid: 1:2.3.6-1.1
- php5-common: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7

Comment: distro? packages? versions?

Comment: Good point - added version to the question.

Comment: Please note that implementing worker + PHP requires that PHP apps and libs are thread safe.

Comment: Thread safety should not be an issue when working with CGI (fcgid) instead of the apache PHP module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd regard 20-30MB per process as quite small.  It's all relative really, but for example most CMS applications will require at least 100MB.  Also your maximum upload size will be constrained by the maximum process size if that matters.

When your server is unavailable, it's likely that the php worker processes are all busy, however that's only a proximate cause.  Something is slowing down your server such that for a while at least, the php processes can't keep up with the incoming requests.  What is slowing down your server is hard to judge, but the 'graceful kill fail' makes me think the process that was to be killed is likely waiting on disk.

Have you logged in while this is happening?  Does the system feel responsive?

In top, look at the process states, and look for the 'D' ones, which are waiting on IO.  Are there many of these?  The 'wa' in the summary up the top is the total amount of time that processes spend waiting on IO.  (It says percent, but that's likely a percentage of one processor's time).  Tools like iotop, atop, and vmstat may also be useful for getting a view on what processes are disk bound, and the extent to which the disk is limiting your overall performance.

Your understanding of what happens when a worker process is not available to take new requests is incorrect.  New requests will not be assigned to it.

1000 requests before killing the worker is high.  I'd suggest dropping it to somewhere between 10 and 50.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pity that I was not yet able to log in during such a "fail" as they are quite rare and only few minutes. However, munin did not record atypical system values (e.g. disk latency or load) for the relevant time frames. According to memory use, no more than 3 or 4 processes have been started - so there should be more than enough buffer...

Comment: Could be go further regarding the 1000 requests before killing the worker process? In my understanding, it takes some time to start the process, so a higher value should be more efficient (given everything works). If I set the value to 50, that would just be enough to server the homepage 10 times (1 HTML + 4 images). Having about 30 requests per second, wouldn't the server spend a lot of time on starting new processes?

Comment: Use atop running as a daemon to keep a record of top style data and extras like per-process disk usage.  When installing on Debian, a ten minute polling cycle is set in /etc/init.d/atop (should really be under /etc/defaults/, but it isn't).  I usually adjust that down to 1 minute.  It requires a fair bit of disk storage though so work out what's right for you.

Comment: To BurninLeo, with the possible exception of a few things like captcha images, php won't be involved in serving the images and so forth on the page, so those won't be part of the count of how many tasks get run before reaping the process.

Comment: Ah - got it. I thought, you'd refered to the apache setting `MaxRequestsPerProcess`, not the fcgid setting `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess`... I'll still have to be careful, as most requests want PHP scripts (images are well cached), but I shall give this a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with Hypopthesis 1. mc0e's advice is pretty solid, so I'm mostly adding to it.

Those log messages that you're seeing suggest that individual processes are locking up under the *prefork* MPM, which gives you much better process isolation than *worker*. I've seen this in a production environment before and it means that you have some misbehaving code.

Between your high max requests per child and your hanging processes, this sets the stage for memory bloat. The documentation specifically covers the fact that [a non-zero value helps to protect against memory leaks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild), but if you set that value too high the benefits are lost. Having your processes hang on top of that just further compounds the overall memory footprint.

This leaves you with two immediate takeaways:

- Lower `MaxRequestsPerChild` by a significant margin, as mc0e was suggesting. This helps to prevent the individual processes from living long enough to accumulate significant memory leaks...but as he said, 20-30M probably isn't that big of a deal.
- Find your bugs. You're looking for memory leaks and execution deadlocks (resource contention as mc0e was suggesting, but also take a look at what your code does when network resources become unreachable or nonresponsive). Running `lsof` on your large processes *may* provide a hint depending on what the code is doing (i.e. file handle leakage, and hitting the max file handle ceiling may be related to the process deadlocks), but otherwise you're looking at code debugging.

Comment: I am afraid, my understanding of memory leaks if limited. As I working with PHP, I have put a memory limit (128 M) n each script. Only in rare occasions, a script will actually need this limit. However, if the limit is exceeded or the script hangs in a deadloop, I usually see a "memory exceeded" or "execution time exceeded" error in my PHP logs. But those I once had, have long been bugfixes - there have not been such errors for a while. So: Am I really looking for memory leaks and deadlocks?

Comment: 1) That memory limit only applies to a single execution of the code. If an artifact of a library you depend on doesn't properly clean up after itself (i.e. a resource is opened that PHP doesn't clean up for you), the result is a resource leak associated with the process. That becomes deadweight which cannot be reclaimed through any re-use of the process, short of the process exiting. 2) `max_execution_time` relies on the process being healthy enough for PHP to police itself. If an Apache process isn't dying, you can be sure that this is not the case. Look really hard at disk/network I/O.

Comment: I do not use non-default packages/modules in PHP and I hope, that the default packages have few memory leaks. However, you never know... Now I understand the issue of leaks and deadloops much better. Thank you very much for the explanation.